# Tutorial for Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework?

Tags: unit-testing

I would like start to learn Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework on VS 2012 Express for Web.
Mainly for ASP.NET MVC project.

I already buy the hard copy of Art of unit test from amazon.
But it is lack of tutorial aims for VS unit testing framework.
So any resource i can have?

Another question, when i research on this forum, 
I found someone said MSTEST is different from VS unit test framework.

Is the VS 2010 Express built-in unit test is subset of VSTS?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all practical purposes mstest is the unit testing framework in Visual Studio 2010. It continues to be the primary unit testing framework in 2012 as well. However now we support extensibility and many 3rd party frameworks like xunit/nunit/gtest etc have adapters for our platform.

For ASP.NET the best place to start is to download the MVC3/MVC4 solutions from Microsoft which contain a rich suite of unit tests with them.